# Fixing error(23, 2) Error parsing expression, misplaced: func

Tags: debugging, godot, gdscript

When I try to use the GDScript code below, Godot gives me the error:

> error(23, 2) Error parsing expression, misplaced: func

Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it? Is there another input node that could give the same results without the error?

```
func _ready():
 position = get_viewport_rect().size / 2
 direction.x = rand_range(-1, 1)
 direction.y = rand_range(-1, 1)
 direction = direction.normalized()
 width = get_viewport_rect().size.x
 height = get_viewport_rect().size.y

func _process(delta):
    position += direction * speed * delta
 if position.x < 0 or position.x > width:
  direction.x = -direction.x
 if position.y < 0 or position.y > height:
  direction.y = -direction.y


 func _on_UFO_input_event( viewport, event, shape_idx ):
 if event is InputEvenMouseButton and event.button_index == 
 BUTTON_LEFT and event.pressed:
 direction.x = rand_range(-1, 1)
 direction.y = rand_range(-1, 1)  
 direction = direction.normalized()
 position.x = rand_range(1, width -1)
 position.y = rand_range(1, height -1)
 speed += 5
```

Comment: Just so you know im following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3lkGGqnHPQ

Answer (score 1):

> the function that i have keeps giving me the error(23, 2) is there another input node that could give the same results without the error?

This looks like symptoms of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/303557), you have a syntax error, but you try to change the algorithm to avoid it. You'd better ask how to fix the syntax errors.

---

It looks like you did not format/indent your code properly: the parser thinks you want to add a function (`_on_UFO_input_event`) to another function (`_process`), which is not allowed (highlighted by the error message `Error parsing expression, misplaced`: it does not expect the keyword `func` in the context of a function). GDScript is a lot like Python, where the *indentation* of the code has a significant importance.

Following the tips from [this official page](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_styleguide.html), you should use four spaces for your indentation.

Your code should end up looking like this.

```
func _ready():
    position = get_viewport_rect().size / 2
    direction.x = rand_range(-1, 1)
    direction.y = rand_range(-1, 1)
    direction = direction.normalized()
    width = get_viewport_rect().size.x
    height = get_viewport_rect().size.y

func _process(delta):
    position += direction * speed * delta
    if position.x < 0 or position.x > width:
        direction.x = -direction.x
    if position.y < 0 or position.y > height:
        direction.y = -direction.y

func _on_UFO_input_event( viewport, event, shape_idx ):
    if event is InputEvenMouseButton and event.button_index == BUTTON_LEFT and event.pressed:
        direction.x = rand_range(-1, 1)
        direction.y = rand_range(-1, 1)  
        direction = direction.normalized()
        position.x = rand_range(1, width -1)
        position.y = rand_range(1, height -1)
        speed += 5
```

Correctly formatting your code is *required* in a language such as GDScript. And it is *very important* with other languages in general: it allows you to read and parse what's going on faster and more easily.

In addition, the `(23,2)` is not a pair of random numbers, it tells you *where* the issue is in your code. It tells you "at this location, I have found this error". Most IDEs allow you to double-click on the error and take you right to there in your code.